# Use of iOS background mode for IM messages (+VoIP) on versions prior to 7

Tags: ios, background, ios7

I have a VoIP application for iOS6 and earlier that uses the VoIP background mode to be able to receive VoIP notifications when in the background. If I use this same TCP channel to also receive IM messages while in the background, is it considered illegal in IOS versions prior to 7.0? I know 7.0 introduced a mode that legitimately allows an arbitrary amount of small data to be downloaded in background mode, but in versions prior to 7.0, there are strict rules on what an app can do in background mode

My question is, this *is* a VoIP app, and we are using it to get VoIP calls, but are also using that channel to get incoming IM messages. Is that considered illegal and will the app be rejected if uploaded to appstore?

Comment: Any thoughts or perspectives from developers who have faced this issue?

Comment: This question is not a good question for Stack Overflow because its very opinion based rather than factual. You are better off talking to apple support about it. Remember Apple has the right to put it on the app store or not allow it for any reason. They may approve something in one case but disapprove in others so unless you actually contact them, you will really not have a good answer.

Comment: True, but I wanted to see if others have done similar things and have either seen success or rejection. Asking apple support is like talking to lawyers.